# Child components get updated properly only after the second click in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have the following component, where review assignments (`props.peerReviewAssignmentIds`) are loaded for a student's own work (related event is `onClick_Submission`) or a peer's work to review (related event is `onClick_PeerReview` ). These events work fine and the related data is loaded successfully. However, there is a problem with updating the content of the child components based on the value of the `props.peerReviewAssignmentIds`, which I elaborate below.

```
const AssignmentItem = (props) => {

    const assignment = props.assignments[props.currentAssignmentId];
    
    const onClick_Submission = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!st_showSubmission) {
            props.fetchPeerReviewAssignmentForStudent(currentUserId, assignment.activeReviewRoundId);           
        }

        set_showSubmission(!st_showSubmission);
        set_isPeerReview(false);
    }

    const onClick_PeerReview = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!st_showPeerReviews) {
            if (st_submissionContiues === false)
                props.fetchPeerReviewAssignmentForReviewer(currentUserId, assignment.activeReviewRoundId);
        }
        set_showPeerReviews(!st_showPeerReviews);
        set_isPeerReview(true);
    }

    return (
        <>             
            {
                st_showSubmission === true && props.peerReviewAssignmentIds.length > 0 &&
                <ReviewPhaseInfoForSubmission isPeerReview={false} />
            }            
        </>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    peerReviewAssignmentIds: state.peerReviewAssignmentReducer.peerReviewAssignmentIds,
    loading_pra: state.peerReviewAssignmentReducer.loading,
    error_pra: state.peerReviewAssignmentReducer.error,
})
```

I will try to explain the problem with an example. When the first time `onClick_Submission` is triggered, `props.peerReviewAssignmentIds[0]` is set to 2, and all the sub components are loaded properly. Next, when `onClick_PeerReview` is triggered, `props.peerReviewAssignmentIds[0]` is set to 1, which is correct. But, the child components get updated according to the previous value of `props.peerReviewAssignmentIds[0]`, which was 2. If the `onClick_PeerReview` event is triggered second time, then the child components get updated correctly according to the current value of `props.peerReviewAssignmentIds[0]`, which is 1. Any ideas why this might be happening?

I further explain my code below.

Below is the `ReviewPhaseInfoForSubmission` component. In this component, based on `props.peerReviewAssignmentIds[0]` value (which gets updated in the parent component above) `etherpadLaterSubmission` variable is created with `props.createSession_laterSubmission` method.

```
const ReviewPhaseInfoForSubmission = (props) => {
    const [st_is_discussFeedback, set_is_discussFeedback] = useState(false);   

    useEffect(() => {
    
        set_is_discussFeedback(true);
        if (props.etherpadLaterSubmission === null) {
            props.createSession_laterSubmission(props.peerReviewAssignmentIds[0], discussFeedback.dueDate);        
        }                   
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="p-1">
            {
                st_is_discussFeedback === true &&
                <ProvideOrDiscussFeedback provide0discuss1revise2={1} isPeerReview={props.isPeerReview} /> 
            }
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    etherpadLaterSubmission: state.etherpadReducer.etherpadLaterSubmission,
    loading_ep: state.etherpadReducer.loading,
})
```

Then, in a child component, `ProvideOrDiscussFeedback` (see below), the props.etherpadLaterSubmission value is used for display purposes.

```
const ProvideOrDiscussFeedback = (props) => {

    return <div className="p-3 shadow">                   
        {
            props.etherpadLaterSubmission &&
            <div>
                <DisplayingEtherpad etherpadSession={props.etherpadLaterSubmission } />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: not even one comment or answer, amazing. I'm here with the same issue on functional components, without having the setState() callback in functional component and no knowledge how to use useeffect to overcome this.

Comment: @clusterBuddy this was long time ago, and I cannot remember I how dealt with this. sorry mate!